# Why [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds] is not returning full screen size?

Tags: ios, uiscreen

I have an app that was created prior to the new iPhone 5 retina widescreen device.
Now i am trying to support this high definition widescreen.

I adjust the main ViewController and the main window XIB files so that they are set to Autolayout. I can verify that the width/height displayed via the IB shows 320 x 568.

However, when I run in simulator, i can see that the height is still 480.
The code im using to print the height (and width) is in the main view controller's viewWillAppear method:

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds]
```

Why is the size.height still 480 instead of 568?

Comment: Are you showing the view inside a tab bar controller?

Comment: show this link for get `iphone 5` screen height [Click this link For your support][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution/17379022#17379022

Comment: @alvinfromDiaspar show my answer and search that link.

Comment: You get full specification of your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to add the iPhone 5 Launch image (`Default-568h@2x.png`) to your project.

The 568 point tall launch image tells iOS to launch your app in 4" mode. If you don't have this image, your app is treated as a 3.5" app. Even if it is 4" compatible.

Comment: wow, an API that has nothing to do with file resources but with hardware but depends on a resource to work! WOW, how crappy is this?

Comment: I have this image and my app is still showing with 320 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Point worth notice - in new Xcode you have to add this image file Default-568h@2x.png to assets