# IOS Simulator not calculating the view bounds correctly

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, view-bound

I'm testing my app using different IOS versions on the IOS Simulator and have run into a problem with IOS 7.1

I'm checking the dimensions in the following way:

```
float height = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height;
```

And when I run the IOS iphone 5 (7.1) simulator the I get 480 as the value for the height.  When I run the IOS iphone 5 (8.1) simulator I get the value that I would expect 568

The Iphone 5 simulator seems to be acting like an IPHONE 4 when running with IOS 7.  Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: Have you checked the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756087/detecting-iphone-6-6-screen-sizes-in-point-values

Comment: That question / answer is describing how to check the various dimensions, my question is asking why the simulator of an iphone 5 is returning the dimensions of an iphone 4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761967/why-uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-is-not-returning-full-screen-size

Do you have a launch image for a 4" screen?

Comment: Thankyou so much, that has fixed my problem.  I would never have thought of that.