# Content is being cut

Tags: ios, xcode

Why is it cutting the sides off? It looks perfectly fine in storyboard. I set the size to 4.7 inch iPhone and applied the necessary constraints, but this happens.

[image: Screenshot from iPhone 6s]

Comment: "the necessary constraints"?  What does that mean?

Comment: Sounds silly, but make sure you have the correct resolution of splash screens set up. On certain phones I've noticed that the incorrect size would clip the screen to the size of the splash screen.

Apple is your friend it just werks and all that.

Comment: Constraints to make them stay where they need to stay. But I don't understand the chipping of left and right of the screen.

Comment: @MathijsSegers yeah all of them are in correct sizes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761967/why-uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-is-not-returning-full-screen-size?rq=1

Comment: Well now, if you're not sharing any code, screens etc. and just assume everything you did is correct we can't really help you.

Comment: @MathijsSegers Thanks! That image was missing. Works perfect now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds silly, but make sure you have the correct resolution of splash screens set up. On certain phones I've noticed that the incorrect size would clip the screen to the size of the splash screen. Apple is your friend it just werks and all that.

So it's a duplicate of this [Why [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds] is not returning full screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761967/why-uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-is-not-returning-full-screen-size?rq=1)

Comment: Vote to close as dupe, rather than posting an answer.